# Movie in which two men ask a dragon three questions

Tags: story-identification, movie, dragons

I'm trying to remember the name of a movie in which two young men ask a dragon three questions.  I remember that one of the men asks the dragon, "Don't we get three questions?"  The dragon responds, "Yes, but now you have only two remaining."  Or something along those lines.

What movie was this from?

Comment: When did you watch this film? And can you recall any more details? Like was it an old movie, or a relatively recent one? Was it set in the West or the Far East? Was it set in modern or ancient times? Etc.

Comment: "*There was a world where people could ask dragons questions if they knew their true name. But only three questions. Some mage dude: <dragon's true name>. Dragon: "Very well, you have two questions." Mage: "Shouldn't there be three questions?". Dragon: "There are two now"*" - https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/comments/a45ti7/outstanding_move/ebbqynk/?context=8&depth=9

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I watched it a few years ago.  I don't know when the movie was made or where the story took place.  I know it isn't any of the five, Dragonheart movies because I watched all of those last week.  I know it isn't from The Hobbit, because it is not Smaug, the dragon.

Comment: This joke has probably been made a few times

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this may be the *[Earthsea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea_%28miniseries%29)* miniseries.

> With the help of Ogion, Ged confronts the Gebbeth and attempts to drown him using a rock, however, it escapes with Ged's likeness and voice. Ged's impersonator becomes a murderer, and Vetch, a magus himself, chases Ged until he realizes Ged is not possessed by the Gebbeth and they decide to hunt it together.
>
> They are attacked by the dragon, Orm Embar, but Ged uses the dragon's true name to bind him and ask three questions. He wastes his first question, but with his second, he learns the Gebbeth's location. The dragon tells him where to find the two pieces of the Amulet of Peace, which when reunited would save Earthsea, but Ged could have asked the true name of the demon.

Here's a clip at the relevant part.

In case that gets taken down, here's a screenshot with them and the dragon around that point:

[image: Image of Ged and Vetch with the dragon, Orm Embar]

Comment: "and ask three questions."  I don't remember that in the book (but it's been a long time).